# Is there any shortcut for parent folder in console?

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

I would like to know if there is any plugins and/or utilities that could make my life MUCH MORE easier.

When moving from folder to folder through console, I can use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key on my keyboard to autocomplete a folder, look for a folder (double tap) or simply to express that I want to go "forward" with my searches.

When coding, the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is used to "push" the code "forward" or to the right. To "pull" the code "backward", you can use the combination of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keys.

Is there an equivalent for, as an example, pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keys to write `../` in the console for me? Or to let me know I'm at the root level and that I can't go "backward" anymore?

**Examples of usage:**

Case 1:

`user@server:/$ cd ~/Desktop/folder1/`

after <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

`user@server:/$ cd ~/Desktop/`(Remove the last written folder. No more backspace spam!! :D )

Case 2:

`user@server:/$ cd`

after <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

`user@server:/$ cd` (Because I'm at root and can't go back)

Case 3:

`user@server:/home/Desktop/folder1$ cd`

after <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

`user@server:/home/Desktop/folder1$ cd ../` (Because I can go back to `Desktop`)

I know that sounds lazy. I know I'm lazy.

Anyways, thanks for the suggestions! (:

**Edit 0:**
Just to be clear. I gave as an example the `cd` command, but what I want could be applied to any command/executable. It would be considered a basic use just like <kbd>Tab</kbd> is used to autocomplete.

This post is related to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135306/is-there-any-shortcut-for-parent-folder-in-console) one.

**Edit 1:**
I know It's the same post from another forum, but I just hoped to get more points of view from this community!

Comment: I'd recommend using `vi` keys to avoid the repetitive keystrokes.  To enable `vi` mode, use `set -o vi`.  Since it's unclear what you're actually asking, I'll leave this as a comment.

Comment: @ctt Could you le tme know what is unclear? I'd like to try to make my question understandable! (:

Comment: I guess it's not so much unclear as it is a duplicate of that other question.  I didn't read it closely at first, but the two questions are identical.

Comment: I know, I'm just looking for more points of view about this topic! (: Some members of other communities told me to post this question here.... So here I am :P

Comment: Hi LoukMo, please avoid cross posts. In addition asking for "plugins and/or utilities" is a Offtopic close reason on SU.

Comment: @bummi Sorry, I wasn't aware of that. As I said, someone from another forum told me to post here.Do you know where I should post this question?

Comment: @LoukMo - this is a reasonable place to post the question, but as mentioned, please try to avoid cross-posting in the future... perhaps close your other questions, or link to this question for people looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the `unix-filename-rubout` operation to a key (see the [`bash` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)):

```
bind 'C-b:unix-filename-rubout'
```

Now pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> will "*rub out*" the last component of the path.

> `unix-filename-rubout`
>
> Kill the word behind point, using white space and the slash character as the word boundaries.  The killed text is saved on the kill-ring.

---

To bind `unix-filename-rubout` to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you may need to add one or other of the following lines to `~/.inputrc` (or perhaps both!):

```
"\e\t": unix-filename-rubout
"\e[Z": unix-filename-rubout
```

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17014/221985) to understand why <kbd>Shift</kbd> is a bit of an odd modifier, and how to find out what your terminal might need.

---

Alternatively, you can get this behaviour by pressing:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> - go back one word
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> - delete to end of line

Note however, that <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> operates at the "*word*" level not "*path element*"... thus a dash (`-`), dot (`.`), etc... will mark the word boundary, and you may need to press it multiple times.

Comment: It's acting like `Alt` + `Backspace` in some ways. I wonder if I can get all these answers to be bonded to the `Shift` + `Tab` keys. If I could upvote, I would. Anyways, thank you for your help! (:

Comment: See my update - binding `Shift` + `Tab` to `unix-filename-rubout` works for me.

Comment: Now, I think I can use the `if` statement to verify if the folder is empty and put `../` in that place. I now need a couple more check to see the other cases (already at root and put another `../` if there's already a `../`). Thanks allot for your help. It's the best answer I got overall!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything that is as "context sensitive" as you are describing (a.k.a. that knows about paths).

However, the keyboard shortcut `Alt-Backspace` will delete the previous word, which can probably get you 98% of what you want.

However, it only fulfills one of your three example cases. Sorry.

Comment: If I could upvote, I would! Thanks for the help! (:

Comment: When the folder name contains dashes `-`, this shortcut erases till you reach a dash. Ex: `./gst-rtsp-server` becomes `./gst-rtsp-`.